# python programme that calculate de the number of moves from one point to another on a chessboard

Tags: python-3.x

Hi everyone I have a problem that I have difficulty resolve in Python. this the statement

Have the function ChessChallenge(str) read str which will be a string consisting of the location of a space on a standard 8x8 chess board with no pieces on the board along with another space on the chess board. The structure of str will be the following: "(x y)(a b)" where (x y) represents the position you are currently on with x and y ranging from 1 to 8 and (a b) represents some other space on the chess board with a and b also ranging from 1 to 8 where a > x and b > y. Your program should determine how many ways there are of traveling from (x y) on the board to (a b) moving only up and to the right. For example: if str is (1 1)(2 2) then your program should output 2 because there are only two possible ways to travel from space (1 1) on a chessboard to space (2 2) while making only moves up and to the right.

If you have a solution please, let me know

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a solution to a task without showing your own work or an attempt at research

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, you need to make an honest attempt and ask questions based on that. Please take the tour [https://stackoverflow.com/tour] and read how to ask[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that is my code

```
def Substr(s):
  arr = []
  for i in s:
    if i.isdigit():
      arr.append(int(i))
  return arr

def Steps(sourceX, sourceY, destX, destY):
  SourceX = sourceX
  SourceY = sourceY
  DestX = destX
  DestY = destY

  i = 0
  j = 0
  while( (SourceX != DestX) or (SourceY != DestY) ):
    #Go up
    if(SourceX < DestX):
      SourceX+=1
      i+=1

    #Go right
    if(SourceY < DestY):
      SourceY+=1
      i+=1
  
  return i+j
    

def ChessChallenge(strParam):
  arr = Substr(strParam)
  SourceX = arr[0]
  SourceY = arr[1]
  DestX = arr[2]
  DestY = arr[3]
  # code goes here
  return Steps(SourceX, SourceY, DestX, DestY)

# keep this function call here 
print ChessChallenge(raw_input())
```

input: "(2 2)(4 3)"
Output: 3

Input: "(1 1)(3 3)"
Output: 6